# How call own script every build in Symfony's webpack encore?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, webpack-encore

I have clean project... only installed Symfony's webpack encore and vue.js. (So basic: index.html, app.js, app.css)

How i can load (and execute) my own javascript every build via webpack encore? And use typeScript features like filesystem (fs)? I was searching in encore [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) and can't find any hint...